# RobinHerbots jquery.inputmask date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, range, jquery-inputmask

I am using [RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) library.

I need to make sure the date inputted in great than current date.
There is code for `yearrange` but I dont see anything for basic 'daterange'.

Using RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask library, how can I make sure the date entered is greater than current/todays date new Date()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue about your question in the [github of RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/818):

RobinHerbots answers that this feature will be implemented in 3.4 and that for now you can use the postValidation callback.

> In the current date alias this is not implemented. However, you can use the postValidation callback to validate if the input is after the current date.
>
> It would be a nice feature, and I will add it to the date alias in milestone 3.4